# Covariance for generic classes

Tags: c#, generics, types

Is there any way in C# to achieve the following:

```
class MyClass<T>  where T : BaseTypeInner {}

class BaseTypeInner {}

class A : BaseTypeInner {}

class B : BaseTypeInner {}

void Main()
{
    MyClass<BaseTypeInner> variant;

    variant = new MyClass<A> (); // ERROR: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UserQuery.MyClass<UserQuery.A>' to 'UserQuery.MyClass<UserQuery.BaseTypeInner>'

    variant = new MyClass<B> ();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# only interfaces can be variant. Quoting C# spec:

> Variant type parameter lists can only occur on interface and delegate types.

So you could declare a generic, covariant interface `IBaseClass<out T>`, make `BaseClass<T>` implement it, and later on cast to `IBaseClass<BaseTypeInner>` instead of casting to the class.

```
interface IMyClass<out T> where T : BaseTypeInner { }

class MyClass<T> : IMyClass<T> where T : BaseTypeInner { }
```

```
IMyClass<BaseTypeInner> variant;

variant = new MyClass<A>(); // works just fine
variant = new MyClass<B>();
```

Comment: Nice, that's much better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to have a base type for the base generic type:

```
class BaseType {}

class MyClass<T> : BaseType where T : BaseTypeInner {}

class BaseTypeInner {}

class A : BaseTypeInner {}

class B : BaseTypeInner {}

void Main()
{
    BaseType variant;

    variant = new MyClass<A> ();

    variant = new MyClass<B> ();
}
```

But, that's not a good idea because I'm using a lower class that's not generic so I'm losing all the details and restrictions I get from using type parameters.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Done.

Answer (score 0):

No, however it is possible to provide custom `CastUp` / `CastDown` methods to achieve this. `ImmutableArray<T>`, part of the .NET BCL, [does this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/41e203011152581a6c65bb81ac44ec037140c1bb/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableArray%601.cs#L1031-L1077).

Comment: Very interesting, but sounds a bit too high-level for me.