# How to convert from Task<List<Derived>> to Task<List<Base>>

Tags: c#, generics, asynchronous, async-await

As the title states, I'm curious if it's possible to convert from `Task<List<Derived>>` to `Task<List<BaseType>>`?

I have a couple of methods that return `Task<List<Derived>>`, and there can be multiple types derived classes. I want to store all the tasks in a list of tasks: `List<Task<List<BaseType>>>` to be executed at a later time.

If my tasks weren't wrapping lists, this would be pretty straight forward: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37819190/5108909)

---

**Edit 1**

Here is the part I'm having trouble with, I'm having issues storing the tasks in a list:

```
// This throws an error (cannot convert derived list to base list)
var tasks = new List<Task<List<BaseType>>>
{
    asyncThing1(), // returns Task<List<Derived1>>
    asyncThing2(), // returns Task<List<Derived2>>
    // ... n number more
};

// Need the list of tasks before I can execute
List<BaseType>[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

**Edit 2**

Above, changed `List<Base>[]` to `List<BaseType>[]`

Comment: Why not just get the results of the `Task` and then it's trivial to convert a `List<Derived>` to `List<Base>`?

Comment: `await YourTask().Cast<Base>().ToList()` ?

Comment: @RandRandom Wrong way round, and you can simplify that to `list.Cast<Base>`

Comment: Is it possible, yes it is. Is there more to this? It seems relatively trivial to do this? Have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG I don't know ahead of time how many tasks need to get queued up. So I need to store a dynamic number of tasks in a list to then all be executed at the same time using WaitAll.

Comment: Yes, so wait for them all to complete and then you have the results to work with.

Comment: @RandRandom You'd need to do that like `(await YourTask()).Cast<Base>().ToList()` to make sure the `Task` is unwrapped first.

Comment: @juharr wasnt sure if the brackets are necessary, hoped it would be smart enough without it

Comment: Yeah like the others said, the `Task<T>` part of this is unrelated/unimportant.  Just await your task(s) like you normally would then use `Cast<T>()`

Comment: The technique that is usually used to accomplish this is dependency injection.

Comment: @DavidG Maybe I'm being a bit obtuse, but I've updated the question to show exactly what I'm having an issue with.

Comment: @Andrew So when you did exactly the thing that was suggested as the solution in the duplicate question that you linked, what happened, and how didn't it work?

Comment: You get an error: "Cannot convert `Task<List<Derived>>` to `Task<List<Base>>`"

Comment: I note in your sample code you alternate between the base being `Base` and `BaseType`.

Comment: @EricLippert Apologies, that was a mistake. I have updated the snippet.

Comment: Now your code is inconsistent with your text. Not a big deal; it's understandable.

Comment: Ah! Fixed that too. Should just use animals like you always do!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As the title states, I'm curious if it's possible to convert from `Task<List<Derived>>` to `Task<List<Base>>`?

No.  Suppose it were legal, and see what goes wrong:

```
Task<List<Giraffe>> t1 = GetGiraffesAsync();
Task<List<Animal>> t2 = t1; // Suppose this were legal
(await t2).Add(new Fish());
```

And now we have a fish in a list of giraffes.

One of those three lines has to be illegal. Plainly it cannot be the first, since `GetGiraffesAsync` returns `Task<List<Giraffe>>`.  Plainly it cannot be the last, since `await t2` produces a `List<Animal>`, and a fish is an animal. Therefore it must be the middle line that is illegal.

Now, you could do this:

```
async Task<List<Animal>> ConvertAsync(Task<List<Giraffe>> t) => 
  (await t).Select(g => (Animal)g).ToList();
```

Or

```
async Task<List<Animal>> ConvertASync(Task<List<Giraffe>> t) => 
  (await t).Cast<Animal>().ToList();
```

or

```
async Task<List<Animal>> ConvertAsync(Task<List<Giraffe>> t) => 
  (await t).OfType<Animal>().ToList();
```

If you wanted to make it generic you could do

```
async Task<<List>Animal> ConvertAsync<T>(Task<List<T>> t) where T : Animal =>
  (await t).OfType<Animal>().ToList();
```

and now it works with giraffes and fish and tigers and so on.

That is, you can asynchronously wait for the original task to finish, and when it is done, you can create a new list of animals from your list of giraffes.  That's perfectly legal. You now have *two* lists, one of giraffes and one of animals.

Or, you could do this:

```
async Task<IEnumerable<Animal>> ConvertAsync(Task<List<Giraffe>> t) => 
  await t;
```

since `List<Giraffe>` is convertible to `IEnumerable<Animal>`.

I would be inclined to write it as an extension method.

```
static class Extensions {
  public static Task<List<Animal>> ConvertAsync<T>(
    this Task<List<T>> t) where T : Animal {
      return (await t).OfType<Animal>().ToList();
  } 
}
```

And now your program fragment is:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<List<Animal>>>
{
  GetGiraffesAsync().ConvertAsync(),
  GetTigersAsync().ConvertAsync()
};
```

Comment: The extension method was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the well explained answer!

Answer (score 2):

Just as a little side note, your posted link was just missing the List part, to make it work for your scenario.

So this was proposed in the other topic:
[Cannot convert type 'Task<Derived>' to 'Task<Interface>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818642/cannot-convert-type-taskderived-to-taskinterface/37819190#37819190)

```
async Task<TBase> GeneralizeTask<TBase, TDerived>(Task<TDerived> task) 
    where TDerived : TBase 
{
    return (TBase) await task;
}
```

What you were searching for is:

```
async Task<List<TBase>> GeneralizeTask<TBase, TDerived>(Task<List<TDerived>> task) 
    where TDerived : TBase 
{
    return (await task).Cast<TBase>().ToList();
}
```

With that you could call it like this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<List<Animal>>>
{
  GetGiraffesAsync().GeneralizeTask<Animal, Giraffe>(),
  GetTigersAsync().GeneralizeTask<Animal, Tiger>()
};
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I was looking for. I wouldn't consider my question a duplicate as it seems to be marked now. Thanks for adding this.