# EF Core and inheritance casting

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

I'm using EF Core 3.0 with .NET Core 3.0.
I have an abstract database model that is inherited by 2 classes. Each one has its own table

So we have Class A as the abstract, and class B and C are inheriting A. B and C have separate tables in the database. they are identical and add no extra fields.

Now here is the problem.

if I try to get a list of Bs from the database as following:

```
List<A> list = await context.Bs.ToListAsync();
```

this works perfectly fine, the following also works:

```
A a = context.Bs.FirstOrDefault();
```

However, the following cause an exception:

```
A a = await context.Bs.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This is the exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[B]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[A]'
```

I think this is due to the fact that IList is defined to be covariant while System.Task isn't

so, is there a way to workaround this? as far as I know EF core supports inheritance just fine, so how is it supposed to be used if this was wrong?

**EDIT:**

I didn't mention an important aspect to complicated the problem even more.

in the provided examples above I used `context.Bs` directly, this simplifies the problem since I know I'm using B.

However in my case I have something called IUserManager, the user manager will resolve the DbSet dynamically, so it will be something like this:

```
IUserManager manager = GetDynamicVersion();
A a = await manager.UsersTable.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

In this scenario, `manager.UsersTable` will return `IQueryable<A>`

Comment: I think you can figure out something in `Eric Lippert's` answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37818935/6797509)

Comment: I've stumbled upon this answer before posting, but this requires knowing the type and adding in the method, in my case the DbSet is resolved dynamically so I can't hardcode the type for casting.

Comment: It would be nice if you provide a real reproducible example. There is no task casting in the current code.

Comment: I added extra details for the problem