# How to return a generic when the actual generic returned type is a sub class of the methods defined return type?

Tags: c#, generics

Consider the code:

```
public Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAliases()
{
    OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<Stuff>> okNegotiatedContentResult 
        = Ok(GET Enumerable "STUFF");

    //wrap stuff in task
    Task<OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<Alias>>> fromResult 
        = Task.FromResult(okNegotiatedContentResult);

    // return result
    return fromResult;
}
```

I get the error:

> Cannot convert expression type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BrokerPad.Core.Models.Views.Alias>>>' to return type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult>'

But [OkNegotiatedContentResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn308866(v=vs.118)) is a sub class of IHttpActionResult which is the generic specified in the return type...

So why does this not work? and how do I get it to work? Is there maybe some way to indicate on the return type that sub classes of the generic class are also acceptable?

Comment: For the "why", see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720751/casting-list-of-derived-class-to-list-of-base-class). Why not just do `var fromResult = Task.FromResult<IHttpActionResult>(okNegotiatedContentResult);`?

Comment: beat me to it..

Comment: Also if you used the async keyword this wouldn't be an issue, as the compiler would take care of it

Comment: @Sweeper The linked answer to the "why" question is not applicable here. As Eric says in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37818935/8967612) to the other linked question: _"`Task<T>` is one of those rare classes that **could** be made safely covariant"_.

Comment: @41686d6564: "could" is not the same as "is". The answer you're linking is still centering on the fact that `Task<T>` is _not_ an exception to the rule as far as the language is concerned.

Comment: Related: [still confused about covariance and contravariance & in/out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631) • [C# generic inheritance and covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263964) • [About the lack of true generic polymorphism and the missing diamond operator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570948)

Comment: @Flater Yes, but you can't use the reason for why it _couldn't_ work for `List<T>` to answer why it _doesn't_ work for `Task<T>`.

Comment: @41686d6564: If the language does not differentiate between the two cases, **which it doesn't here**, then yes you can. The covariance issue with `List<T>` is precisely the reason why the language innately refuses this pattern, and thus also refuses the same pattern for `Task<T>`.

Comment: @41686d6564: Your own link definitively states that **C# does not allow variance on classes**. The language makes no distinction for _which_ class is being used with variance. Whether or not the language is overzealous in its implementation of that variance protection is irrelevant as to _why_ that protection was needed in the first place. Both interesting things to mention, but the former does not invalidate the latter.

Comment: @41686d6564: In other words, the reason why people no longer get free coffee at work is "because Bob used that free coffee to sell to passersby". Even if you didn't sell coffee to passersby and you also cannot get free coffee anymore; that doesn't change the _reason_ for why the rule was instituted.

Comment: To quote David Fowler: [Prefer async/await over directly returning Task](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#prefer-asyncawait-over-directly-returning-task)

Answer (score 1):

> But OkNegotiatedContentResult is a sub class of IHttpActionResult which is the generic specified in the return type...

You're running into the issue of co- and contravariance. Just because `A` can be downcast to `B` does *not* make `C<A>` able to be downcast to `C<B>`.

A simple example to prove the point:

```
public class Animal {}

public class Dog : Animal {}
public class Cat : Animal {}

private List<Animal> GetList() { /* hidden */ }

List<Animal> list = GetList();

list.Add(new Dog());
```

Perfectly valid code, right? Well, what if that hidden method logic was revealed to be:

```
private List<Animal> GetList() { return new List<Cat>(); }
```

Suddenly, you'd be adding a `Dog` to a `List<Cat>`. That's not right!

This is why you cannot return a `List<Cat>` as if it's a `List<Animal>`. And, for your case, why you can't return a `Task<OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<Alias>>>` as if it's a `Task<IHttpActionResult>`.

The solution here is to ensure that the generic type is already set to the base class. In the case of `Task.FromResult`, this is actually a generic method which by default infers the generic type by the type of the passed parameter.

You can either change the type of the passed parameter:

```
Task<IHttpActionResult> fromResult 
    = Task.FromResult(okNegotiatedContentResult as IHttpActionResult);
```

Or you can explicitly state what the generic parameter should be:

```
Task<IHttpActionResult> fromResult 
    = Task.FromResult<IHttpActionResult>(okNegotiatedContentResult);
```

Either is a solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: Again, you can't use the reason for [why it couldn't work for `List<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3720845/8967612) to answer [why it doesn't work for `Task<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37818935/8967612). They're not the same.

Comment: @41686d6564: If the language does not differentiate between the two cases, **which it doesn't here**, then yes you can. The covariance issue with `List<T>` is precisely the reason why the language innately refuses this pattern, and thus also refuses the same pattern for `Task<T>`.

Comment: @41686d6564: Your own link definitively states that **C# does not allow variance on classes**. The language makes no distinction for _which_ class is being used with variance. Whether or not the language is overzealous in its implementation of that variance protection is irrelevant as to _why_ that protection was needed in the first place. Both interesting things to mention, but the former does not invalidate the latter.

Comment: @41686d6564: In other words, the reason why people no longer get free coffee at work is "because Bob used that free coffee to sell to passersby". Even if you didn't sell coffee to passersby and you also cannot get free coffee anymore; that doesn't change the _reason_ for why the rule was instituted.

Comment: _"C# does not allow variance on classes"_ is a valid answer but the argument about `List<T>` does _not_ apply here. Maybe your answer could be reworded to explain that the `List<T>` example is just one of the reasons why the language designers made that decision. As of now, it looks like you're using the same argument for `Task<T>`, which doesn't really work.

Comment: @41686d6564: It is not an argument. It is an **example**. If this were a discussion between the language designers, where the design of the language would be influenced by the discussion's outcome, I 100% agree with you that we shouldn't argue that `Task<T>` should be variance-protected purely because of `List<T>` needing to be variance-protected. But this question/answer isn't between the language designers, and its outcome does not influence the language design. As far as this question/answer is concerned, the language design is considered a constant, and `Task<T>` **is** variance-protected.

Comment: My disagreement is with how the answer is structured. Following your "coffee" analogy, this would be like person A asking "why are we not allowed to make instant coffee at work?" and person B answering "because tea is bad for your health" (what??) - A good answer would be "because kettles can also be used to make tea (which is bad for your health), the company decided to ban kettles altogether at work and consequently, you can't prepare instant coffee". I hope you get what I mean. P.S. Tea is not really bad for health. I love tea. Disclaimer: I'm not a doctor :-D

Comment: @41686d6564: Your analogy doesn't follow suit with what's happening here. A better analogy would be "why can't we microwave food at work anymore? Because Bob kept microwaving fish and the stench would permeate through the building". You're correct that the rule is being overapplied to microwaving _anything_ instead of just fish, and you could microwave e.g. pasta without the stench issue; but the rule says you can't microwave _anything_. The reason *why* you can't microwave anything? Bob and his fish meals. **Regardless** of whether the rule is being overzealously implemented or not.

Comment: @41686d6564: If we were at the board meeting where the rule was being drafted, I agree that we should actively distinguish between foods that do (e.g. fish) and don't (e.g. pasta) create a smell issue. But afterwards, once the rule is locked in, the distinction becomes irrelevant, and it is correct to state that it is the microwaving of fish that led to the ban on microwaving anything, including pasta. You are confusing these two very different scenarios, with a very different topic of conversation in regards to the rigidity of the rule.